# TYPO3 Problem to handle Deprecation #90803

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I am using ObjectManager::get in the following way:

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$sqlSel = $objectManager->get('HGA\\Mairlist\\Utilities\\SqlSelect');
$Setup = $sqlSel->getUid("cr", "lastplay", 3);
```

I have read

> https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.4/Deprecation-90803-DeprecationOfObjectManagergetInExtbaseContext.html#changelog-deprecation-90803-objectmanagerget

several times, but I don't understand it. With `$objectManager->get('HGA\\Mairlist\\Utilities\\SqlSelect')` I got a pointer to this function, but how should do it with `Service $service` ?

How do I get a pointer to my program?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about DI (Dependency Injection). The `objectManager->get()` has been marked as deprecated it will be removed on TYPO3 12. That means that it has to be replaced either with **DI** or with the **GeneralUtility::makeInstance** depending on the usage.

The recommended way to inject your dependencies in your constructor. In your case, it would look like this:

```
use HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlSelect;

class YourClass 
{
    /**
    * @var SqlSelect
    */
    protected $sqlSel;

    public function __construct(SqlSelect $sqlSel)
    {
      $this->sqlSel = $sqlSel;
    }

    public function yourMethod()
    {
      $Setup = $this->sqlSel->getUid("cr", "lastplay", 3);
    }
}
```

Another way to do it is how [Georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2389552/georg-ringer) described. You can use the **GeneralUtility::makeInstance()**

```
use HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlSelect;

class YourClass 
{
    public function yourMethod()
    {
      $sqlSel = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SqlSelect::class);
      $Setup = $sqlSel->getUid("cr", "lastplay", 3);
    }
}
```

In both cases, you have to remember, in order for the DI to work, the class **has to be set on PUBLIC** otherwise you will get the following error:

> Too few arguments to function
> HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlSelect::__construct(), 0 passed in
> /path/to/your/typo3/installation/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php
> on line 3691 and exactly 1 expected

and you can do that on your **Services.yaml**

**your_extension/Configuration/Services.yaml**

```
# Configuration/Services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

HGA\Mairlist\:
  resource: '../Classes/*'

HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlSelect:
  public: true
```

After all that you need to clear all cache, specially the ones that are under the Maintenance Module.

Hope it was helpful.

Best regards

Comment: Hi Aristteidis, I have build this extension mairlist with the extion builder for a while. I can't find any Services.yaml under Configuration. What does it mean?

Comment: Hi Aisteidis, what does `DI` stand for?

Comment: You can add the the Services.yaml file by yourself, the ExtensionBuilder is not that current as it should be. As for the DI, i wrote in the first line what it means. (Dependency injection)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use extbase you could use

```
$sqlSel = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('HGA\\Mairlist\\Utilities\\SqlSelect');
```

Comment: Georg, I have build my extension with the extension-builder and have the opinion, that it is based on extbase. But I changed one `objectManager->get` with your proposal and it is still working. is included into a Controller, but this part is included with `Bootstrap->run` into typoscript.