# TYPO3 DependencyInjection Services.yaml

Tags: typo3, extbase

I switched from TYPO3 V10.4 to V11.5 and had to replace the `objectManager->get`.
For that I already opend [TYPO3 Problem to handle Deprecation #90803](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296654/typo3-problem-to-handle-deprecation-90803).

Due to the fact, that I had more than one `objectManager->get`to replace, I had to extent to `Service.yaml` example to

```
# Configuration/Services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

HGA\Mairlist\:
  resource: '../Classes/*'
  exclude: '../Classes/Domain/Model/*'

HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlSelect:
  public: true
  
HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlUtility:
  public: true
```

[image]

I don't understand the error message and I am also confused about the `/\Services.yaml`.

Is there something wrong with my `Services.yaml` file?

Here the part of `controller` file

```
    **
    * @var SqlUtility $sqlUtil
    */
    protected $sqlUtil;

    public function __construct(SqlUtility $sqlUtil)
    {
      $this->sqlUtil = $sqlUtil;
    }
   /**
    * @var SqlSelect $sqlSel
    */
    protected $sqlSel;

    public function __construct(SqlSelect $sqlSel)
    {
      $this->sqlSel = $sqlSel;
    }
```

**Solution:**

In `Services.yaml`, all my code, starting with `HGA\`, has to be on the same level than _default. That mean, it has to indented one step more (2 spaces).

```
# Configuration/Services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  HGA\Mairlist\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'
    exclude: '../Classes/Domain/Model/*'

  HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlSelect:
    public: true
  
  HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlUtility:
    public: true
```

Comment: Are you in composer mode? Additionally, you only need one constructor. ;)

Comment: No, I am not in composer made. What you mean with only need one constructor? There are two different variables.

Comment: let me edit your question and try it the way i am showing you

Comment: OK, I am waiting, or do I have to something?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas: make your edit to the original post an answer. Even if it is no full answer. It can be enhanced afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the constructor has to be changed. If you have more than one injections, you can define them all in the parameters of the constructor. in your case, it would look like this:

```
use HGA/Mairlist/Utilities/SqlUtil

class yourClass {
   **
   * @var SqlUtil $sqlUtil
   */
   protected $sqlUtil;

   **
   * @var SqlSelect $sqlSel
   */
   protected $sqlUtil;

   public function __construct(
     SqlUtil $sqlUtil,
     SqlSelect $sqlSel
   ) {
     $this->sqlUtil = $sqlUtil;
     $this->sqlSel = $sqlSel;
   }
 }
```

First try this and tell us if the problem persists.

(btw my edit in the original post awaits approval since a day now)

Comment: Aristeieidis, sorry put I have your request for approval only seen this morning.

Comment: I made the changes, but the error message is still the same. That in the error message `/\servives,yaml` is standing, is this ok or is this an error? I also have still one problem of understanding: `@var SqlUtil $sqlUtil` has `SqlUtil ` to be the class name?

Comment: use can use the class name like this ```SqlUtil``` only if you have a use statement. (on top of your classs there should be a ```use HGA/Mairlist/Utilities/SqlUtil)``` otherwiese you  should put the whole namespace next to ```@var```

Comment: the use statements was included. The class names are `SqlUtility` and `SqlSelect`. I have corrected it  in the code sections above.

Answer (score 0):

have you include a namespace in your class? The message say hey found no Namespace "HGA\Mairlist". In Your controller you need

```
<?php
namespace HGA\Mairlist\Controller;

use HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlUtility;
use HGA\Mairlist\Utilities\SqlSelect;

class yourClass
{
    **
     * @var SqlUtil $sqlUtil
     */
    protected $sqlUtil;

    **
     * @var SqlSelect $sqlSel
    */
    protected $sqlUtil;

    public function __construct(SqlUtil $sqlUtil,SqlSelect $sqlSel) 
    {
        $this->sqlUtil = $sqlUtil;
        $this->sqlSel = $sqlSel;
    }
 }
```

And in the INSTALL TOOL you must then Update the Autoloaddump because your not on composer mode.

[INSTALL TOOL - Dump Autoload Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akLv9.png)

Comment: Yes, the namespace is included. Also the use, but the folder Utilities is under Controller, but I think that is ok. Under Tools->Maintenance I have used `Rebuild PHP Autoload Information` and also I deinstalled and reinstalled the extension. And after reinstall it, the error message is popping up.